# iOS 13 status bar style

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar, ios13

I want to change the status bar style on a per-ViewController level on iOS 13. So far I didn't have any luck.
I define `UIUserInterfaceStyle` as `Light` in info.plist (as I do not want to support dark mode) and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `true`. `preferredStatusBarStyle` is called on my ViewController but completely ignored. The `UIUserInterfaceStyle` seems to always override the VC preferences.
How do I get per-ViewController status bar style working on iOS 13? Or is it not supported any more?

Comment: It should work. The one from plist is used before the app is loaded (when splash screen is shown). The rest should be defined with `preferredStatusBarStyle` for each of the view controllers. Note that only top view controllers matter, not embedded ones. So it will work with controller you present but not with controller you for instance push on your navigation controller. To make navigation controller work as well you will need to subclass it forward the setting.

Comment: And this is without setting any option in the plist at all. These are default settings.

Comment: Is your `viewController` embedded inside `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes, it's in a TabBarController that holds NavigationBarControllers, but I already have extensions in place to deal with that. ```extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return selectedViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? selectedViewController
    }
}

extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController?.childForStatusBarStyle ?? topViewController
    }
}``` As I said, `preferredStatusBarStyle` is called but just ignored.

Comment: @MaticOblak did you test on iOS 13? Can you confirm it's working with the latest beta?

Comment: @MaticOblak What compounds the problem is when you modal segue to a ViewController (or NavController) that's not full-screen, so is the modal cards UI of iOS 13 kick in.  Now the status bar is owned by a view controller in Apple's control, so there's no way to subclass it!  How can we control the status bar light/dark at that time?  That ViewController tries to follow dark mode regardless of what I do.

Answer (score 18):

**iOS 13.2, Swift 5.1**

For me nothing worked from solutions mentioned before. After 5 hours I ended up on 
[modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621453-modalpresentationcapturesstatusb) flag .

```
    destinationNavigationController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
    sourceViewController.present(destinationNavigationController, animated: animated, completion: nil)
```

After this `preferredStatusBarStyle` was called in **presented** VC.

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .light {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            return .lightContent
        }
    } else {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Comment: @bezoadam i was trying same . But when my vc was present model. Still i was not able to see the status bar. After i dismiss that vc i can see black color status bar in my home screen..

Comment: But i am presenting with nav bar . Not only with vc

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on iOS13 while it was fine on iOS12 for my app. I have a TabBarController which holds 3 NavigationBarControllers, and I present TabBarController from a previous ViewController. I fixed it by setting .modalPresentationStyle to .fullScreen when presenting:

```
tabbarController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

Maybe it will help you somehow...

Answer (score 3):

In iOS13, there is now a .darkContent option for UIStatusBarStyle. For black text, use this (instead of .default) for preferredStatusBarStyle.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had a similar issue with incorrect `UIStatusBarStyle`. For some view controllers in my app, I need to set a dark status bar style ignoring current system color mode. The problem was I used `.default` value, but in iOS 13 it changes depending on the context. That's why I added a small workaround to handle both iOS 12- and iOS 13+ cases.

```
private extension UIStatusBarStyle {

    static var darkContentWorkaround: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            return .darkContent
        } else {
            return .default
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem on iOS 13 while using navigation controller i was able to change the status bar color using

let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()

navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

but the problem was when i was using present controller the status bar didn't change i used this code on top view controller

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *)
    {
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame)!)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
    }
}
```

you can use your color in "UIColor.systemBackground"

Comment: @famfamfam in ios13 apple changes how status bar color work,in ios13 what color you give to navigation bar the status bar pick that color.You can use below code to keep same Color.
 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
            navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor."YourColor"
            navBarAppearance.shadowColor = nil
            navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
            navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        }